# Двоеточие или тире-с?

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли в данном случае знак двоеточие заменить тире-знаком?

*Совы, у меня только один вопрос, который интересный: вы знаете, например, немецкий?*

Можно ли это заменить на вот это?

*Совы, у меня только один вопрос, который интересный, – вы знаете, например, немецкий?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильный вариант:

*Совы, у меня только **один** вопрос, который интересный: вы знаете, например, немецкий?*

В данном предложении отношения **пояснительные** (это определяется по слову "***один***"). Дополнительно учитывается структура предложения и возможность **интонационного** предупреждения по Розенталю: понижение тона перед  значительно увеличенной / предупредительной паузой.

При постановке тире отношения будут **присоединительными**.

**Правило [Розенталя](https://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189#pp189) :**

5. Вариативны двоеточие и тире в бессоюзных сложных предложениях с **пояснительными** отношениями: Авторов этих писем волновали разные проблемы, но объединяло одно (: —) все они ждали от газеты конкретной и действенной помощи; Всех интересовал только один вопрос (: —) как поскорее выпутаться из создавшегося положения;

Comment: Может, мы в приципе никогда не заменяем двоеточие тире, когда дело идёт о вопросе? Например: *Ответь: когда ты придёшь?* Или здесь можно всё-таки тире?

Comment: Why did you write the version with a colon was the only possible option, then?

Comment: Можно использовать два знака. Но надо сделать ВЫБОР, вот я его и сделала. Все зависит от структуры, интонации, коммуникативности сообщения)) Вот ваш пример: Ответь: когда ты придёшь?  Здесь двоеточие по структуре предложения.  Можно изменить:   И тогда я крикнул – когда ты придешь? Все другое...